# Lua Multiple for-loop statement

Tags: lua, luacode

My `XML` Look is:

```
<contrib-group content-type="all">
    <contrib contrib-type="author"><name><surname>Bronnikov</surname><given-names>Kirill A</given-names></name>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="f1">1</xref>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="f2">2</xref>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="f3">3</xref>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="cqgab7bbaem1"/>
    <ext-link ext-link-type="orcid">0000-0001-9392-7558</ext-link>
    </contrib>
    <contrib contrib-type="author"><name><surname>Santos</surname><given-names>N O</given-names></name>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="f4">4</xref>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="f5">5</xref>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="cqgab7bbaem2"/>
    <ext-link ext-link-type="orcid">0000-0003-4038-5729</ext-link>
    </contrib>
    <contrib contrib-type="author"><name><surname>Wang</surname><given-names>Anzhong</given-names></name>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="f6">6</xref>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="f7">7</xref>
    <xref ref-type="fn" rid="fn1">8</xref>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="cqgab7bbaem3"/>
    <ext-link ext-link-type="orcid">0000-0002-8852-9966</ext-link>
    </contrib>
    </contrib-group>
```

My `Lua` Is:

```
local author_text = function(e)
    local authors = {}
    for _, author in ipairs(e:query_selector("contrib name")) do
         local snm = ""
         local fnm = ""
         for _, nm in ipairs(e:get_children(author)) do
            if nm:get_element_name() == "surname" then
            snm = nm:get_text()
            elseif nm:get_element_name() == "given-names" then
            fnm = nm:get_text()
        end
    end
         table.insert(authors, "\\fmauthor{"..fnm.." "..snm.. "}")
    end
      return table.concat(authors, "")
end
```

My expecting result is:

```
\fmauthor{Kirill A Bronnikov}\fmorcid{0000-0001-9392-7558}
\fmauthor{N O Santos}\fmorcid{0000-0003-4038-5729}
\fmauthor{Anzhong Wang}\fmorcid{0000-0002-8852-9966}
```

I have got author `surname` and `given-names` only. How to get `ext-link` text value?

Comment: I must confess to not seeing a connection between your question on the on hand and TeX, LaTeX, and friends on the other.

Comment: Tbh I don't speak XMLese, but if you add a loop with "contrib" instead of "contrib name" and call "ext-link" you get the expected output (there's probably a better way, but whatever). As @Mico says, it's maybe a bit off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a suggestion: post a complete example, because in yours `luaxml` is not mentioned. The following will work if there's only one author for each contribution, but it should be easy to adapt it to other scenarios:

```
local author_text = function(e)
    local authors = {}
    for _, name in ipairs(e:query_selector("contrib")) do
        local oo = (name:query_selector("ext-link")[1]):get_text() or ""
        local fnm = (name:query_selector("name given-names")[1]):get_text() or ""
        local snm = (name:query_selector("name surname")[1]):get_text() or ""
        table.insert(authors, string.format("\\fmauthor{%s %s}\\ \\fmorcid{%s}", fnm, snm, oo))
    end
    return table.concat(authors, "")
end
```

I understand Lua much better than XML, so I'll gladly include any helpful remark.